# I have been trying to upload ads.txt on AWS S3 bucket, but it fails to upload. Any suggestion?

Tags: amazon-s3

Recent policy changes on Adsense is asking me to put the ads.txt file on domain root. My domain is hosted on AWS. I have been using S3.

I have been trying to upload ads.txt in my bucket but it fails.

Comment: Is there a error message?

Comment: OptionsRequestDenied

Comment: Hey, I got the solution.

Comment: That was quick :) You can also answer your own question here (this way other people searching for the same problem will know what worked for you)

Comment: It was because my ad blocker was on. Tried uploading after pausing that. Worked.

Comment: @BinodGautam Could you make an answer instead of a comment? As stats0007 mentioned, that way it will be easier for others to find the solution in the future.

Answer (score 4):

.txt file failed to upload earlier because ad-blocker on my browser was on. The error message OptionsRequestDenied was because of that. It worked after I paused it.

Comment: Fun thing ad-block is able to block this.

Comment: need to stopI using brave browser when doing some tech stuff